# getpeername Invalid argument after running a server several times

Tags: c, tcp, server

I've got this, taken from beej guide and slightly adapted:

```
socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char nombreSubscriptor[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN+sizeof(int)];
    int port;

    len = sizeof(addr);
    if(getpeername(fdSocketDevuelto, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len)<0){
        perror("GETPEERNAME error");
        close(fdSocketDevuelto);
        exit(1);
    }
 if (addr.ss_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
        port = ntohs(s->sin_port);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    } else { // AF_INET6
        struct sockaddr_in6 *s = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr;
        port = ntohs(s->sin6_port);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
    }

    printf("Peer IP address: %s\n", ipstr);
    printf("Peer port      : %d\n", port);
```

So I run the client and server and send messages to the server, everything works fine, showing like this

```
Peer IP address: 127.0.0.1
Peer port      : 42639
```

But if I close and open several times (sometimes it's in the first 1-2 times I try it, but this has happened less), at some point I'm getting this:

```
 GETPEERNAME error: Invalid argument
```

And before I used the perror and exit(1) in the getpeername I was getting stuff similar to this (it changed slightly in the numbers):

```
Peer IP address: 2325:2ec7:c37f::
Peer port      : 20423
```

I had already asked here [Recv gives Bad file descriptor only sometimes (run the program it works fine, sometimes it does not work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645118/recv-gives-bad-file-descriptor-only-sometimes-run-the-program-it-works-fine-so) but the question is flat out wrong since it's not the recv that has the failure, it's the getpeername function. And I decided to ask again with proper data this time, which I'm unsure if it's the right thing to do.

The question is: why would this happen? Why sometimes it passes and Ip is fine and sometimes is not? It's two completly different runs of the code, I close and run again, and do not compile or do anything. When it gives me the failure, I wait some minutes (this also looks to be changing from time to time) and I can run again and it works just fine again.

Comment: It is the entire socket opening and creation and staying open that the problem.  You do not show other code.  Something is closing the socket descriptor, or clobbering memory.

Comment: I have limited experience, but can that affect two different runs? Shouldn't memory be allocated and variables not shared and so on? As for code, Idk it's pretty long, I try to not just dump everything for people to find in my spagueti code :S

Comment: I don't know.  Spaghetti code is a logical nightmare. Un-spaghetti-fy your code.   I would strip out everything, except beej's code.  Make certain that base code works multiple multiple times.  Then add one separate function.  Test lots. Good rule of thumb: one function does just one thing, correctly. And that one function is the only place your code can go to execute that one thing.  DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself.  Iterate through the project by adding just one function and testing.  By function I mean your declared functions.  Not something like printf - a library function.

Comment: yeah. I started doing all that for this project. Then the code grew too much and it's the largest piece of C code I've put together. And so right now I just try to make it work and printf everything and test for everything that comes to mind. The problem I face right now I do not know ho to meet deadlines and make functions. I create a few in the beggining then everything goes in the main. I do test in different files so there's that. Thanks though!